# Why use a parent pointer to point to a child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

We can just use a child pointer instead. In this case we won't need any virtual functions as well. Why do we do it??

Edit:

All i want to know why is the code :

```
class enemy {
   virtual void attack () {}
};

class ninja : public enemy {
   void attack () {cout<<"A ninja is attacking"<<endl;}
};


class monster : public enemy {
   void attack () {cout<<"A monster is attacking"<<endl;}
};

int main (){
ninja n;
monster m;
enemy *p1 = &n;
enemy *p2 = &m;
p1->attack;
p2->attack;
}
```

more professional and more used than this one (what is its advantages over this one):

```
class enemy {
};

class ninja : public enemy {
   void attack () {cout<<"A ninja is attacking"<<endl;}
};


class monster : public enemy {
   void attack () {cout<<"A monster is attacking"<<endl;}
};

int main (){
ninja n;
monster m;
n.attack;
m.attack;
}
```

Comment: If "We do we do it??" is your question, then a valid answer would be "Dunno". Please add more context, it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: Give an proper example, with code. Often the actual question is "why are you using pointers at all?"

Comment: @U.Windl Why not? If a question is about basic things, it doesn't mean it's bad or unanswerable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat After managing a dozend of programming languages in the last 30 years, using OOP and closures daily, I don't have the slightest idea what the question is about.

Comment: @U.Windl C++ allows you to convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to the base class. I think OP asks what's the point of this feature, if you could just use a pointer to the derived class.

Comment: I just edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *your code*, this feature doesn't do anything useful. It's not "more professional" to write code this way.

---

But consider a different example.

Let's say you're making a game, and you want to have different kinds of monsters in it: `class Goblin`, `class Orc`, and so on.

You need to store them somewhere. You can have one array/container per monster type (such as `Goblin goblin_list[100];` or `std::vector<Goblin> goblin_list;`) but this becomes cumbersome as you add more and more monster types, since you need more and more arrays.

It would be convenient to store all monsters in the same container. And having a common base class for monsters and storing pointers to it lets you to do exactly that:

```
class Monster {...};
class Goblin : public Monster {...};
class Orc : public Monster {...};

std::vector<Monster *> monsters = {new Goblin, new Orc};
```

Now you can process all monsters in an uniform manner.

Comment: But as the OP says that "Monster" has no virtual functions...?

Comment: @Roddy I don't see that in the question. I think OP says that if you don't upcast pointers, you don't need virtual functions (which is not necessarily true).

Comment: "I think OP says"... Yeah, the question is more than a little unclear, but your interpretation may be right :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code shows what polymorphism is really about ("any enemy can attack (in its specific way)):

```
int main (){
  enemy *enemies[2];
  ninja n;
  monster m;
  enemy[0] = &n;
  enemy[1] = &m;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    enemies[i]->attack; // each enemy knows how to attack in its specific way
  }
}
```

With inheritance each descendant inherits methods of the parent and it can adjust (overide) those.
When using the parent type ("parent pointer") the compiler "only" knows the parent methods, but when executing, the methods adjusted in the child (if so) are executed.
That is also called "*dynamic binding*".